# Вставка элемента в список

Tags: java

```
public class app{
    class list{
        char[] symbols;
        int length;
        list next;

        list() {
            symbol = new char[16];
            length = 0;
            next = null;
        }

        list(String value) {
            symbol = new char[16];
            length = 0;
            next = null;
            list currentItem = this;
            for(int key=0; key < value.length(); key++) {
                if(key != 0 && key%16 == 0) {
                    currentItem.next = new list();
                    currentItem = currentItem.next;
                }
                currentItem.symbol[currentItem.length] = value.charAt(key);
                currentItem.length++;
            }
        }

        public void realPrint() {
            int stringLength = this.length();
            list currentItem = this;
            int index = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<stringLength; i++) {
                if(i != 0 && i%16 == 0) {
                    currentItem = currentItem.next;
                    index = 0;
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                System.out.print(currentItem.symbol[index]);
                index++;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "Hello world! Hello world!";
        list str = new list(value); // получается список из двух элементов
        str.realPrint(); // видно что список создался
        list inserted = new list("123"); // создаю новый элемент списка для вставки
        inserted.next = str.next; // следующий элемент за вставленным будет второй элемент списка
        str.next = inserted; // вставляю новый элемент на место
        str.realPrint(); // вот тут теряется третий элемент
    }

}
```

В объекте из строки создаются элементы списка в каждом из которых массив из символов по 16 элементов. мне необходимо вставить новый элемент. Не пойму в чем ошибся. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: во-первых - из 17ти

Comment: во-вторых - там где ты создаешь "новые элемент" - это на самом деле новый список

Comment: и воообще код такой сложный, что нет жаления даже его смотреть =(

Comment: какой же сложный?) я его максимально упростил... два конструктора, вывод и мэйн. суть не в количестве элементов, а в том что элемент (список из одного элемента, без разницы) не вставляется в список

Comment: @Виталий Леонов, а что Вы **наблюдаете**?

IMHO 123 вставится после "Hello world! Hel". Правда кода `realString` я не увидел, но думаю, что там просто `return new list()`

А Вы куда хотели вставить "123"?

Comment: там не realString, а list. щас код поправил. я хочу "123" вставить после "Hello world! Hel", т.е. должно быть так "Hello world! Hel" -> "123" -> "lo world!", а получается "Hello world! Hel" -> "123"

Comment: IMHO у Вас в `realPrint()` ошибка. Вы переходите к следующему элементу списка (по next) только если длина текущего 16.

Вообще в `realPrint()` нужно сделать внешний цикл по всему списку, а для каждого элемента списка свой цикл печати его символов (по длине элемента).

Comment: вот собственно и ответ) спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что написано у вас - ни фига не Java - это какой-то С вперемежку с Pascal :)

Напишите спокойно и вдумчиво 3 метода:

`list.insert(), list.append(), list.delete()` - некий полный набор методов позволяющих оперировать вашим списком как неким объектом. Каждый из методов в плане реализации фигня, а когда все вместе собрано будет ништяк - в чем и сила ООП.